# How i can get first element after sorting\filtering with isotope.js

Tags: jquery-isotope

How to set some class for the first element after sorting\filtering with isotope2?

```
$( function() {
 var $container = $('.isotope');
  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    getSortData: {
      category: '[data-category]'
    }
  });

    $container.first().addClass('first'); <----- i need to add class for first element

  // bind sort button click
  $('#sorts').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
    $container.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });

    $container.first().addClass('first');
  });

  });
  return false;
});
```

Thnx for help:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Isotope v2**

*Optional:* First, You would probably want to make sure to remove that ".first" class every sort with this code. You need to put this before the class addition code to avoid adding having two elements with the ".first" class:

```
$(".isotope").find('.first').removeClass('first');
```

You could access the first item filtered by isotope with:

```
$container.data('isotope').filteredItems[0].element
```

You would add a class to that element with this code:

```
$($container.data('isotope').filteredItems[0].element).addClass('first');
```

Here is a codepen I forked from David DeSandro that demonstrates the code I explained. It makes the first element in the isotope list black:

http://codepen.io/tovly/pen/gbxOMr

The code I added to the codepen is towards the bottom of the javascript and is marked with comments.

Keep in mind you would probably want to bind this code to a click on the sorting and filtering buttons. You should also have the class addition code run when the page loads so that the first item has the ".first" class.

Here is some documentation on this from the creator of isotope. It's under the subtitle "How can I access filtered items in current order?"

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq.html

**For Isotope v1**

You could access the items filtered by isotope with

`$container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms;`

Then you would find the first item in the object and add a class to it:

```
$container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms.first().addClass('first');
```

Comment: thnx, but i saw this docs. It seems that this method doesn't work in isotope v.2(

Comment: @АлексейБондарь You're right. I did not notice that he was using isotope v1. I found documentation for isotope v2 about accessing the isotope items in their current order here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq.html It's `$container.filteredItems`. I'm working on code to illustrate how it's used

Comment: @АлексейБондарь I edited my answer to include instructions for isotope v2. I hope it helps.